# Querying Couchbase DB where

Tags: couchbase

I need to query Couchbase database with following conditions.
I have documents for Employee entities like

```
{
  "first Name" : "ABC",
   "role" : "developer",
   "department" : [
                    {
                      "name" : "HR",
                      "country" : "Germany"
                    },
                    {
                      "name" : "Finance",
                      "country" : "USA"
                    },
                    {
                      "name" : "HR",
                      "country" : "USA"
                    }
                  ]

}
```

how to fetch those documents where department is "HR" in COuchbase ?

Answer (score 2):

Using CouchBase, you could use either Views or Index. I offer you a "map-view" solution.

The map function would look like this :

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type === "employee") {
        if (doc.department && doc.department.length) {

            for (var i = 0; i < doc.department.length; i++) {
                emit(doc.department[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: *This map function us the type "employee". It's highly suggested to group your documents as if they where "tables" by linking them with a key. For example, every employee document could be of type "employee". Also, This map function will emit the same key twice. You can easily change  the JavaScript to emit  only unique values or you could use a reduce function.*

To query the view, you would do something like this:

`GET http://localhost:5984/dbname/_design/yourDesignName/_view/byDept?include_docs=true`

**Output**:

```
{
    totalRows: 3,
    rows: [{
        "id": "ABCEmployee",
        "key": "HR",
        "value": null,
        "doc": {
            "first Name": "ABC",
            "role": "developer",
            "department": [{
                "name": "HR",
                "country": "Germany"
            }, {
                "name": "Finance",
                "country": "USA"
            }, {
                "name": "HR",
                "country": "USA"
            }]

        }
    },
    {
        "id": "ABCEmployee",
        "key": "Finance",
        "value": null,
        "doc": {
            "first Name": "ABC",
            "role": "developer",
            "department": [{
                "name": "HR",
                "country": "Germany"
            }, {
                "name": "Finance",
                "country": "USA"
            }, {
                "name": "HR",
                "country": "USA"
            }]

        }
    },
    {
        "id": "ABCEmployee",
        "key": "HR",
        "value": null,
        "doc": {
            "first Name": "ABC",
            "role": "developer",
            "department": [{
                "name": "HR",
                "country": "Germany"
            }, {
                "name": "Finance",
                "country": "USA"
            }, {
                "name": "HR",
                "country": "USA"
            }]

        }
    },
    ]

}
```

If you want to query let's say every documents that have the department "HR", do the following :
`GET http://localhost:5984/dbname/_design/yourDesignName/_view/byDept?include_docs=true&key="HR"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.And if I want to use WHERE clause then how can I give this condition ?

Comment: If you're using views, you need to emit the keys that you want to query (like if you were using a WHERE) then query using complex keys ["HR","John"] Else, if you might want to get a look to Query

Comment: Thanks for your patience.My requirement is the way we use where clause WHERE role = 'developer' and "department that contains HR as its name".Can you please help me with this

Comment: @Sakalya Views or Cloudant Query(Index)?

Comment: @Sakalya he just told you how to do it. CouchDB doesn't have Where clauses... You can only search using emitted keys in a view. The keys are used as index that you can slice trough using a matching start_key end end_key...Either way simply read the couchdb book.